# How to use event listener to enable sequential clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I researched on this site but I am having trouble understanding how to utilize an event listener in jquery so on the *second* or *fourth* click specifically something changes on my css?

In other words, I know how to on click change something but how to make it so on the first click it does nothing but on the second click it does?

Comment: I'm wondering if "sequential" means "once user clicks somewhere else clicks counter should be reset to 0 for that element". is it correct?

Comment: Do you want to count clicks on element or only on the body?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this is too broad; both answers are along the same lines.

Answer (score 3):

Count the clicks.

```js
var click_count = 0;
$('#test').click(function() {
  click_count += 1;
  if (click_count == 2) {
    alert("second");
  } else if (click_count == 4) {
    alert("fourth");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Click me!</button>
```

You'll need a separate variable if you plan to repeat this, otherwise it will count the number of times *any of the things* have been clicked. Here's a closure-based demo:

```js
// Generalised function
function click_counter(element, func) {
  var click_count = 0;
  $(element).click(function(){
    click_count += 1;
    func.call(this, click_count);
  });
}

// Example use
click_counter($('#test1'), example);
click_counter(document.getElementById('test2'), example);

function example(clicks) {
  if (clicks == 2) {
    alert("Second click!");
  } else if (clicks == 4) {
    $(this).append("<br />Fourth click!");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test1">Click me!</button>
<button id="test2">Click me also!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I realize now that I need a variable. Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet.
Is that the kind of things you want to achieve?

```js
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("countclicks");
for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
  elms[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    colors_on_multiple_clicks(this);
  });
}

function colors_on_multiple_clicks(elm) {
  var clicks = 1 + (parseInt(elm.getAttribute("clicks")) || 0);
  elm.setAttribute("clicks", clicks);

  if (clicks == 2) {
    elm.classList.add("red");
  }
  if (clicks == 4) {
    elm.classList.remove("red");
    elm.classList.add("green");
  }
  if (clicks == 8) {
    elm.classList.remove("green");
    elm.classList.add("blue");
  }
  if (clicks == 12) {
    alert("You can stop now, I can't change color anymore!");
  }
  if (clicks == 16) {
    alert("I did warn you. I'm deleting myself!");
    elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
  }
}
```

```css
.countclicks {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.red {
  background: #a44;
}

.green {
  background: #4a4;
}

.blue {
  background: #44a;
}
```

```html
<div class="countclicks">
  <p>Click here, and again. And again…</p>
</div>
<div class="countclicks">
  <p>Click here, and again. And again…</p>
</div>
```

Note that I didn't use jQuery.
**Update:** I modified the code to store the counts of clicks in an attribute in the applicable elements.

I hope it helps.